# MATLAB/General Loops, Using a value inside a loop

Tags: matlab, loops, while-loop

I'm confused on loops.

I want this MATLAB while loop to stop when the *p* **inside** the loop becomes the same as the initial *p*. Obviously I can't have *p ~= p* otherwise the loop won't start, so how would I do this as the original p is used for calculations inside the loop

e.g if p=18 I want to use that to calculate a and the next p I'll use in the while loop but I want the while loop to stop when 18 is that next p

```
p = input(prompt1)
q = input(prompt2)

while(??? ~= p)
    a =floor((10*p)/q)
    p= (10*p) -(an*q)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no *`p` inside the loop* and *`p` outside the loop*. There is only one `p`. If you want, set `p_original = p;` before the loop. Then, make the loop an infinite loop, check the condition at the end, and break out if the condition is satisfied.

```
p = input(prompt1);
q = input(prompt2);

p_original = p;
while 1
    a = floor((10*p)/q);
    p = (10*p) - (an*q);
    if p == p_original
        break;
    end
end
```

If you don't want to have that infinite loop, add a variable that keeps track of whether or not you have looped once. Inside the loop, set it to `false`.

```
first_loop = true;
while p ~= p_original | first_loop
    a = floor((10*p)/q);
    p = (10*p) - (an*q);
    first_loop = false;
end
```